# How can I fire off a dynamically created list of http requests in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, migration, angular8

In a previous AngularJS app that I am migrating to Angular 8, I had a function that would download functions by binding them and placing them in an array, waiting to be called using a reduce function.  For example:

```
function stageForDownload() {
  $scope.files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.checked) {
      $scope.downloadFunctions.push(downloadFile.bind(null, file));
    }
  });
}

function downloadStaged() {
  $scope.downloadFunctions.reduce(
    function (prev, next) {
      return prev.then(next);
    }, Promise.resolve())
    .then( /* do something now that all files are downloaded */ );
  }
}
```

This code would essentially resolve promises in a one by one fashion until the list of functions were empty.  As in Angular 8, the structure of promises works in a different way (meaning they use the ECMA 6 implementation now) and I am unsure of how to migrate this code.  Furthering my confusion, the HttpClient angular provides now returns an Observable which can be subscribed to; and while rsjx's `forkJoin()` method seems to support exactly what I want to do, it will not accept a list of bound functions.

I simply just need to know when all of the functions are completed, as they are voids that run an export service method to download a file.  So I do not necessarily need to return / subscribe to any data from these methods that are being reduced.

Edit:

There are two more functions involved that I forgot to mention.  Here is downloadFile, which is responsible for calling the exportService.

```
        function downloadFile(file) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $scope.date = formatDate($scope.datepicker.selectedDate);
            $scope.fileDate = dateToYMD($scope.datepicker.selectedDate);

            exportService.exportData(file.FileNamePrefix + " " + $scope.fileDate + ".xlsx", 'SOME_API_LOCATION' + $scope.date, file).then(
                function () {
                    deferred.resolve();
                },
                function (error) {
                    deferred.reject();
                    notificationService.displayError("Internal Error!");
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

And here is the exportService itself:

```
(function (app) {

    'uuse strict';

    app.factory('exportService', exportService);

    exportService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

    function exportService($q, $http) {

        var service = {
            exportData: exportData,
            createFilename: createFilename
        };

        function exportData(filename, url, data) {

            var config = {
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            };

            return $http.post(url, data, config).then(
                function (response) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var data = response.data;
                    var status = response.status;
                    var headers = response.headers();
                    var octetStreamMime = 'application/octet-stream';
                    var success = false;
                    var contentType = headers['content-type'] || octetStreamMime;
                    try {
                        // Try using msSaveBlob if supported
                        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                        if (navigator.msSaveBlob)
                            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                        else {
                            // Try using other saveBlob implementations, if available
                            var saveBlob = navigator.webkitSaveBlob || navigator.mozSaveBlob || navigator.saveBlob;
                            if (saveBlob === undefined) throw "Not supported";
                            saveBlob(blob, filename);
                        }
                        success = true;
                        deferred.resolve();
                    } catch (ex) {
                    }
                    if (!success) {
                        // Get the blob url creator
                        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
                        if (urlCreator) {
                            // Try to use a download link
                            var link = document.createElement('a');
                            if ('download' in link) {
                                // Try to simulate a click
                                try {
                                    // Prepare a blob URL
                                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
                                    var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                                    link.setAttribute('href', url);
                                    // Set the download attribute (Supported in Chrome 14+ / Firefox 20+)
                                    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
                                    // Simulate clicking the download link
                                    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                                    event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                                    link.dispatchEvent(event);
                                    success = true;
                                    deferred.resolve();
                                } catch (ex) {
                                }
                            }
                            if (!success) {
                                // Fallback to window.location method
                                try {
                                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: octetStreamMime });
                                    var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                                    window.location = url;
                                    success = true;
                                    deferred.resolve();
                                } catch (ex) {
                                    deferred.reject();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return deferred.promise;
                },
                function (error) {
                    return $q.reject(error);
                });
        }
    }
})(angular.module('app'));
```

So it appears my problem is not necessarily firing off a dynamically created list of http requests, **but rather how to convert promises using $q into ECMA6+ promises.**

Comment: angular http.get returns an observable that you can call `.toPromise()` which you can put in an array. Then you can call [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). to trigger and wait for completion

Comment: I added some more info to the OP.  I believe the exportService can still use subscribe for the http request, but I should make a new promise for the logic which downloads the arraybuffer as a xlsx file, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `from` to turn `Promise` into `Observable`.

```
const observables: Observable<any>[] = promises.map(promise => from(promise));
```

After that, you can unleash RxJS. You can use forkJoin to get an `Observable` of all your promises:

```
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(files => { 
  // do things with files
});
```

The way forkJoin is implemented it will only fire once the observables *complete*. It will not be an issue here, but if you want to batch requests that do not complete, consider `zip`.

If you want to do use `HttpClient`, you would just have a different source of your observables.

```
const observables: Observable<any>[] = urls.map(url => this.httpClient.get(url));
```

but the `forkJoin` would be the same. The key is that `forkJoin` accepts an array of `Observables`.